# What is the minimum dependence to use QtNetwork classes

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries, qtcpsocket, qsslsocket

I want to use `QTcpSocket` and `QSslSocket` in my shared library, but I confused by necessity to create `QCoreApplication`. Maybe I'm mistaken and there is no need to create `QtCoreApplication` ? What is the minimum dependence to use Qt Sockets?

Answer (score 2):

By using QTcpSocket, you're likely to want an event loop. This is provided by [QCoreApplication](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html), or [QApplication](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html) if you're using widgets.

Comment: Indeed. Although you can use the network functionality without an event loop, it is highly discouraged.